# Schema.getGlobalDescribe is not working properly

Tags: apex

i want to get all fields of all the sobjects but its not giving all objects :

```
Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
       for (Schema.SObjectType typ : schemaMap.values() )
       {
       String sobjName = typ.getDescribe().getName();
       System.debug('the objects are:' +sobjName);
       Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(sobjName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
       System.debug('the map of fields'+fieldMap);
       list<String> fields = new list<String>(fieldMap.keySet());

        Map<String, Schema.DescribeFieldResult> finalMap =  
       getFieldMetaData(schemaMap.get(sobjName).getDescribe(),fields);

       }

public static Map<String, Schema.DescribeFieldResult> getFieldMetaData(  
  Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dsor, list<String> fields)
{
Map<String,Schema.DescribeFieldResult> finalMap = new Map<String, Schema.DescribeFieldResult>();
  Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> objectFields = dsor.fields.getMap();
  for(String field : fields){
    if (objectFields.containsKey(field)) {
      Schema.DescribeFieldResult dr = objectFields.get(field).getDescribe();
                    finalMap.put(field, dr);
                }  }
      System.debug('==== finalMap of external fields'+finalMap);

  return finalMap;
}
```

Comment: What is the output? Do you get any error

Comment: i am not getting all the objects that exists in the org.

Comment: Have you verified the sObject visibility with respect to the running user context (the above mentioned code will be executed in particular user context). Also the mode ( sharing / without sharing ) in which the class is executing.

Comment: hi Reshma , thanks for the reply but I have verified this code its gives all the sobjects:                                                                                                                    Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
       for (Schema.SObjectType typ : schemaMap.values() )
       {
       String sobjName = typ.getDescribe().getName();
       System.debug('the objects are:' +sobjName);}

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new `finalMap` instances for each SObject but not holding on to references to those. Another map keyed by the SObject name would solve that so the first key is the SObject name and the second key is the SObjectField name:

```
Map <String, Map<String, Schema.DescribeFieldResult>> m =
        new Map <String, Map<String, Schema.DescribeFieldResult>>();
...
for (...) {
    ...
    Map<String, Schema.DescribeFieldResult> finalMap =  
                getFieldMetaData(schemaMap.get(sobjName).getDescribe(),fields);
    m.put(sobjName, finalMap);
}

return m;
```

(If you man that `schemaMap` does not include all the SObjects I don't know a cause for that.)

Comment: thanks Keith ..but my question is I am not getting all objects. Can you help in this ?

Comment: @pauladam You mean your `schemaMap.values()` call doesn't return all the values you expect? Or that your code fails to return them all? If its the former make sure the API version is set to the latest.

Comment: hi Keith,...api version is 38.0 .

Comment: @pauladam Suggest you clarify your question. In your last comment on your question you say "its gives all the sobjects". My answer proposes how to capture those and return them. What exactly is the problem that remains to be solved?

Comment: if I run this piece of code ,its giving all the objects..but if i use it in above mention code, It is not showing all the objects.                                                   Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); for (Schema.SObjectType typ : schemaMap.values() ) { String sobjName = typ.getDescribe().getName(); System.debug('the objects are:' +sobjName);}